# For a sequence $(a_n)$ in set X, the sequence ($x_n$) is both injective and has the same range as ($a_n$)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $X$ is a set such that there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $X$ with the property that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $m>N$ such that $a_m\notin\{a_1,...,a_N\}$. Then $X$ contains an injective sequence $(x_n)$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $r\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_r=a_n$. (That is, the sequence ($x_n$) is both injective and has the same range as ($a_n$))

Here is how I am thinking to construct the sequence, but I am not sure if it works, and I am not sure how to prove it.

Suppose that $X$ is a set such that there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $X$ with the property that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $m>N$ such that $a_m\notin\{a_1,...,a_N\}$. 
    Define the sequence $(x_n)=g(a_n)$ as follows:\

For all $n,m,r\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r<n$ and $m<n$ let $$x_n=g(a_n)=\begin{cases}
 a_n & ,\text{if} \ a_n\neq a_m \ \text{and} \ a_n\neq x_r\\
 g(a_{n+1}) &,\text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

What the hypothesis is telling you is that the image of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a countably infinite set, so all you need to do is to take the subsequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} = (a_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that removes all the repeated values. So, for example,

Let
$$x_1 = a_1,$$

By hypothesis, there is a $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that a $a_{M} \neq a_1,$ so consider the set $N_2= \{n\in \mathbb{N} | a_n \neq a_1\}.$ 
$N_2 \neq \emptyset$, since $M \in N_2$. By the well ordering principle, the set $N_2$ has a least element. So let $n_2= \min{N_2}.$ If you take the least element, you make sure that you don't miss out any distinct values, that is, if $m < n_2$, then $a_m=a_1$. With this, you can define
$$x_2=a_{n_2}.$$

By the same argument you can build $x_3.$ In this case your set is $N_3= \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | a_n \neq a_1$ and $a_n \neq a_{n_2}\},$ which is not empty by your hypothesis, so take $x_3 = a_{n_3},$ where $n_3 = \min{N_3}  $. Inductively, you can build,

$$x_1 = a_1, \ldots, x_k = a_{n_k}$$
This procedure can go on indefinitely (why?), and satisfies what you need.

Hope this helps!